# Paginator doens't store search parameters

Tags: php, parameters, paginator

i'm using jpinedo.webcindario.com/scripts/paginator at my search script, but when i click on the page 2 the parameters from the first search are lost (i get my own message for "you need to type at least 2 characters")

how can i make it work?
this is my search.php:

```
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['q']);
$option = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['option']);
```

that are coming from my index.php, search module
(the rest are just the same from the script example, a simple search)

i tried:

```
$_pagi_propagar = array("q","option","search");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make your search GET based instead of POST based. This is because clicking a link is always GET based, so it's easier to change the search submit to GET than change the links to POST, since that requires a fair bit of javascript.